# Why does removable USB storage not show up in Launcher or Files as a regulat USB stick?

Tags: partitioning, usb, mount

Using 17.04 in "Try before install" mode

A 'normal' USB, as in formatted with a MBR partition table, by Windows shows up with a usb-stick icon in Launcher, and is ejectable from a Files sidebar.

But formatting the same device with a GPT partition table shows a "disk" icon, like internal disks do, and is not ejectable from Files.  In never even appears in the side bar, and you cannot eject it from "other places".  An error modal dialog pops up with "Unable to unmount volume" "Operation not permited".

But `sudo umount` works fine.

My guess is that Ubuntu is treating it like an internal disk drive.

In both cases the drives even when being mounted via entries in `/etc/fstab` instead of udisks2, and the entries are the same except for the device name

So why is the GPT formatted stick being handled this way?  I'd like for it to show up in the sidebar of Files like the MBR formatted stick.

Formatted via

```
parted -s --align optimal /dev/sdc \
 mktable gpt \
 mkpart primary fat32 0% 100% \

mkfs.vfat -F32 /dev/sdc1

# mount and copy files to disk here

parted -s /dev/sdc set 1 boot on
```

The goal is to be able to mount disks, including both GPT and MBR bootable disks made by Rufus (in windows)  The GPT that inspired the question was supposed to be a clone of the Rufus method, only made in Linux.

[added]

Looking at a real Rufus USB, I comes up with a different icon that either of the other.  This time its icon is a box (instead of a stick) impressed with a USB tree symbol.  It does show in the side bar.  It is ejectable.

Looking at Rufus' GPT partition the two prominent differences seem to be a name of "Microsoft Basic Data" and a msftdata flag on the partition. so that's where I will try looking next

Comment: Does `sudo mount /dev/sdXY` work?

Comment: @Raphael Yes, `sudo mount ` works as expected

Comment: Can you tell me exactly how you formatted the pendrive, so that I can reproduce the issue and check what's causing it. Because otherwise it gets detected as it should normally.

Comment: @Raphael I edited that information, and some additional into the question.  The GPT disks were supposed to be like those made by the Rufus utility under Windows.  But that particular GPT wasn't, even though it worked OK otherwise  (booted when the boot flag was set too)

Comment: I think the `msftdata` flag makes the difference. Try it.

Comment: it seems like `parted` turns off `msftdata` when the `boot` (aka `esp`) flag gets set.  I can't set them both on.  I think the esp flag is the villain  ( `gdisk` shows it as Code EF00. while the rufus disk says Code = 0700.  I was setting boot after copying program data into the formatted disk.  Maybe its not needed as the Rufus USB doesn't have it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some background information may help. On GPT disks, the "flags" in libparted based tools, including both GParted and `parted`, are a mixture of two things: GPT attributes, any number of which can be applied simultaneously to any partition; and GPT type codes (which are 16-byte GUID values internally), of which every partition has precisely one. This can create a lot of confusion, since a partition can have multiple flags, but sometimes applying one flag automatically removes another, since those two flags are actually type codes. What's more, libparted doesn't explicitly display some type codes; those are just considered implicit for the filesystem type. (This is true of the Linux Filesystem type code, for instance.) Also, the type code to identify the EFI System Partition (ESP) has *two* flags associated with it in recent versions of libparted: `boot` and `esp`. It used to be just `boot`, but that had an entirely different meaning on MBR disks. (I suspect the intent is to deprecate the `boot` flag on GPT disks to minimize confusion on this point in the long term, but I'm not positive of that.)

Thus, *some* of what you're seeing is related to the type codes. There are three of them that seem to be relevant to your question:

- **Linux Filesystem** -- This type code (0FC63DAF-8483-4772-8E79-3D69D8477DE4) identifies Linux filesystems (ext2/3/4fs, Btrfs, etc.). It is not explicitly flagged in libparted, but in `gdisk` it has a type code of 8300.
- **Microsoft Basic Data** -- This type code (EBD0A0A2-B9E5-4433-87C0-68B6B72699C7) identifies FAT, exFAT, or NTFS data partitions, including Windows boot partitions. In the past, Linux "piggybacked" on this type code, which created problems. It's identified in libparted by the "msftdata" flag, or in `gdisk` by a type code of 0700.
- **EFI System Partition (ESP)** -- This type code (C12A7328-F81F-11D2-BA4B-00A0C93EC93B) identifies a partition that's used by EFI-based computers to boot. It should hold a FAT32 filesystem. As noted above, it's identified in libparted by the "boot" and (in newer versions) "esp" flags, and in `gdisk` by the EF00 type code.

Note that libparted-based tools are terrible if you really need to know what a partition's type code is, since only a handful of type codes are reported. If you want to know the type code, use `gdisk` instead. Even its summary display is a bit limited; if it doesn't recognize a GUID type code, it displays it as FFFF. You can find the complete GUID value by using the `i` option on the main menu, which displays full partition information. (`gdisk` uses a shorthand 2-byte type code rather than the full 16-byte GUID in its user interface for simplicity. Most `gdisk` type codes correspond to their MBR equivalents, but multiplied by 0x100. For instance, on MBR, Linux filesystem partitions are 0x83, hence 8300 in `gdisk`.)

I've just done some experiments, and for me, the Unity Files program handles Linux Filesystem and Microsoft Basic Data partitions identically -- at least, as far as I tested. In both cases, inserting a disk results in it appearing in the menu, being automounted, and being ejectable. ESPs, though, did not appear in the Files menu and were not automounted. This is at least somewhat sensible, since some environments might create empty (and largely pointless) ESPs on hard disks and removable media. (OS X's Disk Utility creates an ESP whenever you create a GPT, for instance.)

Note that most EFIs will boot from any FAT partition, even if it's not marked as an ESP. This isn't guaranteed behavior, though; it's conceivable that some ESPs are more fussy about that. In fact, I'm pretty sure this was true of the old Gigabyte Hybrid EFI, which was horrible in many ways. (I've long since rid myself of the one example of this firmware that I had, so I can't double-check this detail.)

Tools like Rufus, which are designed to create a bootable disk, may do so by creating an ESP -- but I haven't checked to see what Rufus actually does, so I don't know if Rufus does so, or if it might do different things depending on the program's settings.

The Wikipedia article on GPT can expand on this.  The sections involving the GUIDs are at

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table#Partition_entries
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table#Partition_type_GUIDs

Answer (score 0):

The issue occurred when attempting to set the partition bootable.

On a GPT partitions, the `boot` flag is synonymous with `esp` flag

An `esp` flag is mutually exclusive with the `msftdata` flag.

It is the `msftdata` flag that makes drives show up in the `files` window  sidebar and be ejectable

So you can't set boot on a GPT disk partition and have it in the side bar.

But it turns out you don't seem to need `esp` set to boot on a UEFI machine anyway.  So just don't set boot.